# Jmeter Perfmon Listner - Validating the Swap counters

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a DB performance test and I am reading OS counters from SQL Server box. The SWAP metric which uses Page In and Page Out counters are showing huge values. As per my knowledge the PageIn should be < 100.

Can somebody help me understand this counters as its go beyond 500000.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be concern only if you have high [page out](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3780229) values, because page in means read from memory without the overhead of reading from disk:

> If an application calls a page and it is in the RAM, then it is a "page in" occurs. If an app calls for a page from memory, and that page is currently stored on the hard disk and has to be read back into the RAM, then a "Page Out" occurs. A **"Page-out" slows the operation of the system down because it has to read the data from a hard disk into RAM first**

Comment: Thanks for the response. So Page In is the physical memory (RAM) the system really use and PageOut is the virtual memory (SWAP) that system use when the RAM is full? So in my Image the blue line (number 480000) shows the number of page files reads within the RAM and it doesnt matter how big it is with respect to the performance of the system. Is it correct?

Comment: @Rakesh133 Correct it's less important, except PageOut is when the requested page isn't in RAM, need to fetch from disk

Comment: Yes. And PageIn is when the number of pages uses within the RAM (not from SWAPs) correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where did you get this "knowledge" regarding `PageIn should be < 100`, as per Microsoft metric description:

> Pages Input/sec is the rate at which pages are read from disk to resolve hard page faults. Hard page faults occur when a process refers to a page in virtual memory that is not in its working set or elsewhere in physical memory, and must be retrieved from disk. When a page is faulted, the system tries to read multiple contiguous pages into memory to maximize the benefit of the read operation. Compare the value of Memory\Pages Input/sec to the value of  Memory\Page Reads/sec to determine the average number of pages read into memory during each read operation.

[image]

Given [page size in Windows is 4K](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tims/2010/10/28/pdc10-mysteries-of-windows-memory-management-revealed-part-one/) why do you expect page reads to be limited to 400 kilobytes?

Try correlating JMeter's output with [Windows Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10) and you should see similar numbers (even equal if you go for the same zoom levels)

[image]

Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for more information on OS metrics collecting during JMeter tests.